# When Checkbox value is null. Program throws this error" Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."

Tags: c#, .net

When the checkbox value in database is null it throws error. When it is `0` or `1` it works as expected.

```
if (Request.QueryString["Sckey"] != null && Request.QueryString["Sckey"].ToString() != "")
{
    string str_sql1 = "select ScenarioSeq,ScenarioName,FileName,ScenarioNotes,IsUpperCase from Scenario where ScenarioKey=@ScenarioKey;";
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(str_sql1);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScenarioKey", str_ScKey);
    DataSet ds2 = this.DA.GetDataSet(cm);

    DataRow dr = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0];
    txt_ScenarioName.Text = dr["ScenarioName"].ToString();
    txt_ScenarioNotes.Text = dr["ScenarioNotes"].ToString();
    ch_Uppercase.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["IsUpperCase"]);     
}
```

Comment: Yes, as the error says that cannot be cast into other types. What would be null as a boolean? You'll have to check it separately.

Comment: instead of direct binding with - dr["IsUpperCase"], you should first validate whether it is null or not. If null, set to False, if not null, set it to Convert.ToBoolean as you have done

Comment: Apart the inappropriate question formatting and irrelevant commented code dropped strait from original code...You trying to convert null to boolean value. What it should be? You trying to convert nothing to true or false.

Comment: Probably null checking should be given there: `ch_Uppercase.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(IsDBNull(dr["IsUpperCase"]) ?? false);`. `Checked` property is boolean, just receiving `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 3):

`Null` in the terms of RDBMS has a *special meaning*, it stands for *unknown*, *invalid*, *can't be applied to* etc., and that's why can't be cast (what `bool` value (`true`, `false`) should be used for *unknown*?). Try  `dr.IsNull("IsUpperCase")`:

```
 ch_Uppercase.Checked = !dr.IsNull("IsUpperCase") && Convert.ToBoolean(dr["IsUpperCase"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this..

```
ch_Uppercase.Checked = 
     Convert.ToBoolean(dr["IsUpperCase"] == DBNull.Value? 0: dr["IsUpperCase"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(dr["IsUpperCase"], out number);
ch_Uppercase.Checked = number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct it like this.

```
ch_Uppercase.Checked = !dr.IsNull ? Convert.ToBoolean(dr["IsUpperCase"]) : false;
```